# How to unregister event(removeclass) in calendar like html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I try to create calendar like HTML tables, I would like to know how to removeclass them.

My desired result is

- When I click `1`or`2`or`3`,then only `1`,`2`,`3`'s classes will be removed .
- When I click `10`or`11`or`12` then only `10`,`11`,`12`'s classes will be removed.

Are there any needs for referring to `next` or `previous` element?

Are there any sophisticated way to achieve this?

Thanks

**Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.yellow').removeClass('yellow');
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div {padding: 5px;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
.yellow {background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>


<script>
  let html = ''
  html += '<table>';
  let i = 0;
  for (let w = 0; w < 3; w++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
      i = i + 1;
      html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  html += '</table>'
  document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;

  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 19, 20, 21, 12, 26, 27, 28].map(String);


  $("td")
    .filter(function() {
      return arr.includes($(this).text());
    })
    .addClass('yellow');
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps when you build your array to make this calendar chart, group the sections as key array/value pairs. So your array would look like `const arr = array( 1 => array ( 1, 2, 3 ), 2 => array ( 6, 7), 3 => array ( 10, 11 ), 4 => array (19, 20, 21) 5 => array ( 26, 27 28 )`  then build your calendar and remove each group using its parent key?

Comment: @Heisenberg, did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
 $(function() {
  $("td").click(function() { 
   $(this).removeClass('yellow');    
  });
});
 
 let html = ''
  html += '<table>';
  let i = 0;
  for (let w = 0; w < 3; w++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
      i = i + 1;
      html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  html += '</table>'
  document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;

  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 19, 20, 21, 12, 26, 27, 28].map(String);


  $("td")
    .filter(function() {
      return arr.includes($(this).text());
    })
    .addClass('yellow');
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div {padding: 5px;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
.yellow {background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>
```